# Does Rails call methods in the order they are written or some order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am following Michael Hartl's tutorial and one problem I was having was I kept getting this error `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` for my show page view where I have:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>            
                <%= gravatar_for @user %>
                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
        </section>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Now in my User Controller I had the show method under the create and new method when I was getting this error:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params) 
    if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end


  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

So then when I removed the show method from and put it above the create method I stopped getting the error. So does rails call methods in some order? just need help understanding why.

Show method moved above create:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params) 
    if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  end





  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Comment: The above are methods definitions, not method calls. Order doesn't matter. You got a nil @name because User.find was unsuccessful--you went to the url of a nonexisting user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an extra `end` command floating in the middle of your controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params) 
  if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
  else
      render 'new'
  end
end

end  # This end doesn't belong here
```

This is causing Rails to think that it has reached the end of your controller code before it really has and this is why you are seeing different behavior based on whether you place the `show` method before or after this extra `end`.  When your `show` method was above this it was included in the controller.  When your `show` method was below this it was not included in the controller.

You will want your controller to look like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params) 
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

end  # This end statement closes the UsersController class
```

Then the order of your methods won't matter.

Also, in the future, please include the information about the line of code that is printed next to the error message.  This will make it easier to help debug the problem.